# Insert break between characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I'm trying to format many texts on MS Word, and these texts come from a website.

The problem is that when I paste it on Word, breaks are not included. So, I have a huge paragraph with every parts stuck altogether.

I managed to separate most of the parts by using the function Find and Replace, but one problem remains :

Each time there is a lowercase character directly followed by an uppercase character, I need to insert a break between them.

For instance : Roses are re**dV**iolets are blue.

I tried to write a macro on VBA but it doesn't work, and returns me "Error 424 : Object Required". At this point, I haven't practiced any VBA for years, and I'm lost. If someone could help me, that would be great !

Here's what I wrote :

```
 Dim doc As Word.Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
        
    
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim Char1 As String
    Dim Char2 As String
    
    With doc.Range
        With Selection.Find
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop
         .MatchWildcards = True
         .Text = "[a-z][A-Z]"
         .Execute
            If Find.Found = 1 Then
              string1 = Selection.Text
              Char1 = Left(string1, 1)
              Char2 = Right(string1, 1)
              string1 = Char1 + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + Char2
            End If
        .Replacement.Text = string1
        End With
    End With
```

Thank you !

Comment: `True` in VBA is -1, and `string1` equals `[ ]`, but I can't find where the return from `.execute` is stored ..

Comment: I would inspect the incoming text closely: it *could* be that there is a \r (carriage return) between them, but no \n (linefeed). In that case it would simply be a matter of replacing \r on its own by \r\n. Depends on the incoming text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you are looking for with the below mentioned code. Please see if it works for you too.

```
Sub Find_Replace()

 Dim string1 As String
 Dim Char1 As String
 Dim Char2 As String

  Do While ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute("[a-z][A-Z]", , , True)
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[a-z][A-Z]"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
         string1 = Selection.Text
         Char1 = Left(string1, 1)
         Char2 = Right(string1, 1)
         string1 = Char1 + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + Char2
        End If
         .Execute ReplaceWith:=string1
       End With
       
  Loop
       
     MsgBox "Task Complete"
       
End Sub
```

Comment: My idea behind this is to first execute Find to select the target text, then retrieve the text using Selection and execute Find again to replace it with the desired text.

Comment: That works ! Thanks a lot, this will help me for the next few years to format the courses I enter then on Anki ! I can't say how many hours I lost this year by doing it manually ...